# How to properly encode non english characters in java

Tags: java, utf-8, character-encoding, ascii

I am trying to read and process some content of different languages, I am trying to create a string object with UTF-8 encoding to make sure all the characters are processed correctly. But some of the characters are not handled properly by java. How to make it process correctly.

```
String content = "Εισιτήρια";
System.out.println(new String(content.getBytes(), "UTF-8"));
```

**Output:**

Εισιτή�?ια

Comment: Your code works fine here.

Comment: works fines for me.  Maybe the codepage for your console is wrong

Comment: `System.out.println(content);` should work too

Comment: I have provided System.out.println as an example to show the behavior of the code. I am actually not printing it in the console, after creating string object like above I am sending it in a REST API payload which is storing data in database and when I read it back or check it in the database the string is like above.

Comment: so there are many points for failure.  Have a look at code posted by BalusC both on this site and other sites. He has a ton of information.  Otherwise [Please add a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: it seems the following code of GsonBuilder is causing this issue. How to force  GsonBuilder to encode the characters properly while creating json from java object. "String gson = new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().excludeFieldsWithModifiers(java.lang.reflect.Modifier.TRANSIENT).setLenient().create().toJson(this).toString()"

Comment: That's not an MCVE ...

Comment: Java (C#, JavaScript, …) doesn't have a datatype for UTF-8-encoded strings (other than `byte[]`) because `String` (UTF-16) fulfills almost all such needs.